# Could this kind of texture be created procedurally?

Tags: texturing, procedural

Could this kind of texture be doable in Blender procedurally? The yellow dotted line in the following reference pic is marking what I'm struggling to create.

[image]

With musgrave and noise textures I've gotten this far, but I'm unsure how to do that tattered fade between light and darker blue:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ask a new question, this one has been answered

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of using a musgrave node as in your .blend-file, I used two noise nodes where one of them controls the scale of the second one to make the fade "grainy". I also made the ColorRamp gradient a bit softer. See the node tree below:

[image]

Comment: Nice solution - although using a variable Scale on that second Noise can produce unintended consequences... the graininess will become more pronounced the further you are away from the texture origin. An alternative would be to Add the noise to the Vector coordinates instead and this should be more consistent over distance/scale.